# networkActivityIndicatorVisible

Tags: iphone, xcode

Is this code correct to use with the networkActivityIndicatorVisible?

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    UIApplication* app2 = [UIApplication sharedApplication]; 
    app2.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES; 
    [self loadSources];  // Loads data in table view
    app2.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO; 
}
```

Teo

Comment: You are violating your developer agreement with Apple by asking this question. At the moment, iOS 4 is in beta, and on Apple's web site, they say, "iPhone SDK 4 GM seed, iOS 4 GM seed, and iTunes 9.2 beta are pre-release software and are considered Apple Confidential Information." While I personally hate this because it hinders developers, I do respect it.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that.
I'll just change the post and if that's not ok i'll delete it.
Thanks

Answer (score 17):

Since `NetworkActivityIndicatorVisible` can be set from several points while a connection is still active, you need to track the number of calls that enable/disable it. The following `UIApplication` category does just that using a static variable:

```
// file UIApplication+NetworkActivity.h
@interface UIApplication (NetworkActivity)
- (void)showNetworkActivityIndicator;
- (void)hideNetworkActivityIndicator;
@end

// file UIApplication+NetworkActivity.m
#import "UIApplication+NetworkActivity.h"
static NSInteger activityCount = 0;
@implementation UIApplication (NetworkActivity)
- (void)showNetworkActivityIndicator {
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] isStatusBarHidden]) return;
    @synchronized ([UIApplication sharedApplication]) {
        if (activityCount == 0) {
            [self setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
        }
        activityCount++;
    }
}
- (void)hideNetworkActivityIndicator {
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] isStatusBarHidden]) return;
    @synchronized ([UIApplication sharedApplication]) {
        activityCount--;
        if (activityCount <= 0) {
            [self setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
            activityCount=0;
        }    
    }
}
@end
```

Now import `UIApplication+NetworkActivity.h` in your client code and call

```
// on connection started:
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] showNetworkActivityIndicator];

// on connection finished:
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] hideNetworkActivityIndicator];
```

If your concern is that the indicator blinks for only a second, you don't need a background process. Just call `[self performSelector:@selector(loadSources) withObject:Nil afterDelay:0.1]` so the UI thread has time to start the network indicator animation before you block the main thread.

Comment: This looks nice. I want to point out that it should probably be made thread safe because users will often want to call this from the background.

Comment: For iOS 4.0 and later, use `libdispatch` or `NSOperation` for asynchronous background tasks instead of `performSelector:`.

Answer (score 5):

If you're not using AFNetworking (https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) already you can check out their network activity indicator implementation in AFNetworkingActivityIndicatorManager.

If you do choose to use this library for your network access, they handle the network activity indicator for you automatically.  All you need to do is make one call in your AppDelegate to set it up, they do the rest of the work for you.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager] setEnabled:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

An shorter solution for tracking multiple activities - again using a UIApplication category and a static variable:

```
@interface UIApplication (NetworkActivityIndicator)
    - (void)toggleNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:(BOOL)visible;
@end

@implementation UIApplication (NetworkActivityIndicator)
-(void)toggleNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:(BOOL)visible {
    static int activityCount = 0;
    @synchronized (self) {
        visible ? activityCount++ : activityCount--;
        self.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = activityCount > 0;
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: Doesn't this one allow the count to go negative?

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved it. I used `performSelectorInBackground` to execute the load data into tableView

```
-(void)beginLoadSources {
    [self loadSources];  // Loads data in table view
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO; 
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(beginLoadSources) withObject:nil];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use thins code in your ExempleUIWebView.m
before - (void)viewDidLoad

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
  [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
  [ProgressHUD dismiss];
  }
  and use this after - (void)viewDidLoad

[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
    [ProgressHUD show:@"Loading Privacy Policy" Interaction:NO];