# iOS 7 Don't show network activity indicator

Tags: ios, networking, statusbar

I know this question has already been asked for various times, but none of the solutions worked for me.
How do I hide the network activity indicator in the iOS status-bar?
The most websites tell you to use the following code, but the indicator still appears in the status bar.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible: NO];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17081003/hide-activity-indicator-in-status-bar

Comment: Stack Overflow has a great search feature. Try searching "hide network activity indicator" and look at all the results: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hide+network+activity+indicator

Comment: Finally, this is most likely what you want to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032192/networkactivityindicatorvisible

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's possible that some other code (static library / open source you're using) is setting the visibility to `YES`.

I would set a symbolic breakpoint at `-[UIApplication setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:]` and see which piece of code is responsible.

Follow [these instructions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_a_symbolic_breakpoint.html) to set a symbolic breakpoint.

Comment: Thank you I found the problem: I am using parse analytics which activates the visibility